# Why shouldn't Value Objects reference their owners?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I've read that in most cases Value Objects shouldn't reference their owners.

a) I interpret this as saying that association should be unidirectional, traversable only from owner to VO?

b) Why shouldn't VOs reference their owners?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a) I interpret this as saying that association should be
>   unidirectional, traversable only from owner to VO?

Yes.

> b) Why shouldn't VOs reference their owners?

- Because it isn't needed. Value objects are simple objects and potential behavior in a VO is generally only related to itself or another instance of its own class.
- Because value objects can be contained in multiple owner types, possibly in multiple aggregates.
- Because value object equality is based on all the fields being equal, and you don't want color Green of John's eyes to be considered any different from color Green of Laura's eyes just because of an odd Owner field.
- Because bidirectional associations are discouraged (even in entities) anyway.

Answer (score 4):

It is a code smell for [value objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) to reference their owners because it suggests a violation of [the SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) as well as [overly-tight coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling). By definition, a value object is one that does very little other than hold values. Therefore it is immutable and devoid of most logic (business logic, lifecycle logic, etc.).

Comment: I agree that VO should be immutable, but disagree about it being devoid of business logic. On the contrary, it is a fitting place for BL, especially in a functional style.

Comment: Fowler's definition makes no claims about business logic. Moreover, PEAA was released slightly earlier than the DDD book where the definition of VO was extended. Recent focus on functional programming extends the definition as well.

Comment: The definition is, however, very specific about the objects being **small,** which – at least in my experience – is not long-term compatible with significant business logic.

Comment: @Matt Ball: "It is a code smell for value objects to reference their owners because it suggests a violation of the SRP ..." I assume it is VO that violates SRP and not its owner?

Comment: @eulerfx: "I agree that VO should be immutable ... " I know VOs shouldn't perform any operations on entities especially to adhere to Side-Effect-Free functional style of programming, but I thought there may be cases where domain concept could be implemented by VOs simply referencing their owners ( in other words, VOs wouldn't be using owners in their operations )?! In such cases, why would referencing its owner make VO mutable?

Comment: @user437291 _"I assume it is VO that violates SRP and not its owner?"_ yes.

Comment: @user437291VOs *can* reference their parent, it is just discouraged because of the additional dependency which can present issues such as in persistence. If needed, it would be better to make the dependency explicit as a method parameter rather than a reference.

Comment: @eulerfx: A - "it would be better to make the dependency explicit as a method parameter rather than a reference" I assume you mean one of VO's methods should take owner as a parameter? But in that case VO would no longer be following Side-Effect-Free functional style of programming?! B - Anyways, so VO just referencing owner doesn't make it mutable? C - I know this is vague question, but I assume there aren't many cases where domain concept should be represented with VO simply referencing its owner ( and if there is such a case, we should find some other way to represent the concept )?

Answer (score 2):

I follow this principle because I want my POJOs to be designed independent of the client that uses them and decouple it from the client at the code level.  That way, they become portable.